# I have no ListView Component but it's still getting back the Invariant violation error in react native

Tags: react-native, listview

I have no Component like ListView, Icon, Spinner, and others stuff, but it's still getting back the Invariant violation error in my react native project. Can anybody help me? I added my package.json file here. When I type "npm list" in my terminal I get some npm error like the image two. I'm not sure if this problem is happening for my image two errors.

[image]

[image]

```html
{
  "name": "eon-bazar",
  "description": "MStore Pro - Complete React Native template for e-commerce",
  "author": "InpireUI",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "setup": "./scripts/setup.sh",
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "postinstall": "patch-package"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/viewpager": "^4.1.6",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^8.4.6",
    "@unimodules/core": "^5.1.2",
    "api-ecommerce": "^0.0.36",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "base-64": "^0.1.0",
    "by": "^0.2.3",
    "create-react-context": "^0.2.3",
    "css-select": "^3.1.0",
    "currency-formatter": "^1.4.2",
    "eslint": "^3.14.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.13.0",
    "expo": "^39.0.0",
    "expo-ads-admob": "~8.3.0",
    "expo-ads-facebook": "~8.4.0",
    "expo-analytics": "^1.0.8",
    "expo-asset": "~8.2.0",
    "expo-av": "~8.6.0",
    "expo-constants": "~9.2.0",
    "expo-facebook": "~9.0.0",
    "expo-font": "~8.3.0",
    "expo-google-app-auth": "^7.0.0",
    "expo-google-sign-in": "~8.3.0",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~8.3.0",
    "expo-localization": "~9.0.0",
    "expo-web-browser": "~8.5.0",
    "firebase": "^7.9.0-0",
    "grpc": "^1.24.3",
    "html-entities": "^1.2.1",
    "lodash": "4.17.11",
    "moment": "2.24.0",
    "monet": "0.9.0",
    "native-base": "^2.13.14",
    "oauth-1.0a": "1.0.1",
    "parse": "github:parse-community/Parse-SDK-JS#master",
    "patch-package": "^6.1.2",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "postinstall-postinstall": "^2.0.0",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-instantsearch": "^5.1.0",
    "react-instantsearch-dom": "^5.7.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.3.tar.gz",
    "react-native-animatable": "1.3.2",
    "react-native-app-intro-slider": "2.0.1",
    "react-native-clean-form": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-collapsible": "1.4.0",
    "react-native-country-picker-modal": "^0.7.1",
    "react-native-credit-card-input": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-dev-menu": "^4.0.2",
    "react-native-drawer": "git+https://github.com/luyx2412/react-native-drawer.git",
    "react-native-expandable-section-flatlist": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-fluid-slider": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.7.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-localization": "^2.1.6",
    "react-native-masked-text": "1.11.1",
    "react-native-modalbox": "1.7.1",
    "react-native-paper": "2.15.0",
    "react-native-parallax": "^0.3.0",
    "react-native-radio-buttons": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.13.0",
    "react-native-render-html": "4.1.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.11.0",
    "react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-side-menu": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.6.0",
    "react-native-star-rating": "^1.0.9",
    "react-native-svg": "^5.5.1",
    "react-native-svg-uri": "^1.2.3",
    "react-native-swipe-list-view": "1.5.3",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0-rc.3",
    "react-native-web": "^0.13.18",
    "react-native-windows": "^0.41.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-header-buttons": "2.2.0",
    "react-navigation-props-mapper": "^0.4.0",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.5.6",
    "react-redux": "6.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-actions": "2.6.5",
    "redux-persist": "^5.9.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "required": "^1.0.0",
    "reselect": "4.0.0",
    "sentry-expo": "^2.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.0",
    "tcomb-form-native": "^0.6.13",
    "urijs": "1.19.1",
    "url": "^0.11.0",
    "url-parse": "1.4.4",
    "util": "0.11.1",
    "uuid": "3.3.2",
    "validate.js": "^0.12.0",
    "wpapi": "^1.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "25.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^8.3.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.1",
    "jest": "25.1.0",
    "reactotron-react-native": "3.2.1",
    "reactotron-redux": "3.1.0"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "ecommerce"
  ],
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: Have you tried resetting yarn/npm cache? `yarn start --reset-cache`?

Comment: I'm using npm, I already do, npm cache clear ---force, npm start  -- --reset-cache, watchman watch del-all, etc.

Comment: @karlmarxlopez can you suggest to me any other way.?

Comment: It might be a 3rd party library issue. Can you include the package JSON content?

Comment: Yup, please see the answer below.

Comment: Where? I cannot see it?

Comment: @karlmarxlopez please have a look now in the comment section

Comment: @karlmarxlopez Now you can check